# Mock gives "raise except" error

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test my program. 
I have a side effect in my mock object

```
from models import MyObject
     mock_obj.objects.get.side_effect = mock.Mock(side_effect=MyObject.DoesNotExist)
```

The test works and passes when I have this in the function that I am testing:

```
import models

   try:
        obj = models.MyObject.objects.get(id=1)
    except Exception:
        return True
```

However when I change this to:

```
import models
        try:
            obj = models.MyObject.objects.get(id=1)
        except models.MyObject.DoesNotExist:
            return True
```

It gives me this instead of returning True:

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/test/test_my_function.py", line 40, in test_get_job_not_exist
>         response = my_function.my_function(request_mock, 1)
>       File "/home/handlers/my_function.py", line 35, in get_job_with_id
>         obj = MyObject.objects.get(id=id)
>       File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1062, in __call__
>         return _mock_self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
>       File "/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1118, in _mock_call
>         raise effect
>     DoesNotExist
```

Why is this happening? MyObject is a Django model object

Comment: Is it supposed behavoir to raise an exception? [https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect]

Comment: @Gang Yes I am mocking an exception and is expecting the unit test to return true. But it is not doing that. When I except a much broader exception it does return true

Comment: how about `with self.assertRaises(models.MyObject.DoesNotExist): obj = models.MyObject.objects.get(id=1)` instead of the `try` and `except`, this is just a wild guess.